# VSCode for Play framework using Java and Sbt (Scala) on WSL

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, sbt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to setup a 'Play Framework' code base on my Visual Studio Code. The code is written in Java and uses Sbt(Scala) to download references/packages, compile and run. I have installed the 'Java extension pack' and the 'Sbt plugin' by lightbend on VsCode. The 'sbt compile' and 'sbt run' runs fine and I am able to run the application using

```
"sbt -jvm-debug 5005 'run 9001'"
```

I have the following in my launch.json to attach to this process

```
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Attach) - Remote",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "port": 5005
    }]
```

The process attaches and the breakpoints are hit. However, I am not able to inspect any of the variables/statements. Please refer error below

[image]

Cannot evaluate because of compilation error(s): form cannot be resolved.
None of the references are resolved

[image]

Comment: Are these libraries properly referenced? if yes, try to clean the workspace and run

Comment: I used 'sbt clean', 'sbt compile' and 'sbt run'. It all works fine. The server spins up an instance and I hit my breakpoints too.

Comment: try to use ecclipe, intellij or netbeans for play framework.

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been a long time since the question has been asked but I just wanted to share what worked for me.

This seems to be a problem with the project setup in Visual Studio Code and not necessarily a problem with the Debug configuration. I setup the Play Framework project in VSC as it is [explained here](https://yongjie.codes/guides/java-play-sbt-on-vscode/) (especially the changes in the `pom.xml` file) and it worked great for me. I was even able to run the application in Debug mode and evaluate the variables just fine.